# Multiple markers at this line - Map.Entry is a raw type. References to generic type Map.Entry<K,V> should be parameterized

Tags: java, for-loop, linkedhashmap

```
Map params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
params.put("name", "Jinu Jawad");
params.put("email", "helloworld@gmail.com");
params.put("CODE", 1111);
params.put("message", "Hello Post Test success");
StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
for (Map.Entry param : params.entrySet()) {
    if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
    postData.append('=');
    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
}
```

/* getting error at the for loop .can anyone help me on this.? - */

Answer (score 0):

Error is with the Map Declaration,

```
Map params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

it should be like follows.

```
 Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
 params.put("name", "Jinu Jawad");
 params.put("email", "helloworld@gmail.com");
 params.put("CODE", 1111);
 params.put("message", "Hello Post Test success");
 StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
 for (Map.Entry param : params.entrySet()) {
    if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
        try {
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey().toString(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

Comment: thanks but this one worked as i was using java 1.5 .Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();